JSX files are not deploying
I'm trying the deploy ReactJS (JSX) files / project in Vercel, Render.com, etc. Deploying tools. But I get an error that says, "for Vite React JSX in Render.com, I get this error

Running build command 'npm run build'... npm error code ENOENT npm error syscall open npm error path /opt/render/project/src/package.json npm error errno -2 npm error enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/render/project/src/package.json' npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm error enoent npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2024-08-25T05_04_09_857Z-debug-0.log ==> Build failed  ==> Common ways to troubleshoot your deploy: https://docs.render.com/troubleshooting-deploys", But I have the proper file path still I get this error.  can anyone share the instructions about deploying the React JS Project Which is friendly to apply or deploy in online ?

I want to know whether I can run the react JavaScript JSX files as deployed project in Render.com, Vercel etc.?



Does npm run build works for you locally?


Where is your package.json located? is this a correct path? /opt/render/project/src/package.json
if not, probably it's wrongly set in vite.config



Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
